# Sql statement question

Tags: sql, select, distinct

*I have a table, which contains logs and has the following scheme:*

```
USER | DATE | LOG
x      x      x
...
```

Now, I want to make *ONE* query to retrieve every `(USER, DATE)` pair, where `DATE` is the latest for this user.

I was thinking about something like *(pseudo):*

```
SELECT ... FROM (TABLE) ORDERED BY DATE, DISTINCT BY USER
```

*But I'm not sure if that's gonna work.*

Is it correct that `DISTINCT` would take the **first possible** dates in this query, therefore yielding the required result? Or the order of elements in `DISTINCT` query is undefined?

---

If yes, how should I solve this problem *(this is the case I can't add new table, such as `users` and, for example, cache the lastest dates there)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I want to make ONE query to
>   retrieve every (USER, DATE) pair,
>   where DATE is the latest for this
>   user.

```
select user, max(date)
from yourtable
group by user
```

You might want to add `ORDER BY user`.

Since both *user* and *date* are reserved words for most SQL dbms, this is more likely to run.

```
select "user", max("date")
from "yourtable"
group by "user";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports windowing, you can do this with

```
SELECT user, date, log FROM
(SELECT user, date, log, row_number()
  OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn) FROM table_name) AS subq
WHERE rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT on it's own will not quite do what you want,  since you want the largest date PER USER, you need to do a subquery.  The order by in the query will ensure that you get teh largest date.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT USER
         , DATE
         , LOG
      FROM TABLE AS T1
     WHERE DATE = (SELECT TOP 1 DATE
                     FROM TABLE AS T2
                    WHERE T2.USER = T1.USER
                 ORDER BY DATE DESC)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do top 1 in my sub query.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution would be

```
select user, max(date)
from tableName
group by user
```

This does what you ask - but if you add "log" to the query, you need to use a subquery.